# SQL select query record based on whether record exists with foreign key pointing to it

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a "multipliers" table that has a foreign key "push_id" pointing to records in the "pushes" table. This is a many to one relationship.

Some push records don't have multipliers, but others do.  What I'm trying to accomplish is a SQL query that selects the latest push record which has multipliers, and then query the multipliers themselves.

Something like:

```
push_id = result_of("SELECT id FROM pushes ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 WHERE <multiplier record exists where push_id == id>")

multipliers = result_of("SELECT * FROM multipliers LIMIT 1 WHERE push_id == push_id")

print(multipliers)
```

I may also want to add a constraint on the pushes.  As in I only want multipliers from a certain type of push.

Not much SQL experience here - any help appreciated.
Thanks.

### UPDATE

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * from 
(
    select m.*, p.type,
    from multipliers m
    inner join pushes p
    on m.push_id = p.id
    where p.type = 'CONSTANT'
) AS res1 where res1.push_id = ( 
    select max(push_id) from    
        (
            select m.push_id
            from res1
        ) AS res2
);
```

and I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'res1' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only interested in pushes that are linked to a multiplier, this can be achieved without a join between the tables. The following query based on your own attempts demonstrates the general idea:

```
select *
from multipliers
where push_id is not null and
push_id = ( select max(push_id)
            from multipliers
          )
```

If you want to constrain by push_type, assuming your model is normalized to have that information only within the pushes table, you are going to need a join such as:

```
select m.*
from multipliers m
inner join pushes p
on m.push_id = p.id
where p.type = 'Whatever push type'
and m.push_id = (
                  select max(push_id)
                  from multipliers
                );
```

> **EDIT** based on new requirement in question to partition by push_type:

You can extend the previous query using nested membership tests as follows to achieve the required result

```
select m.*
from multipliers m
inner join pushes p
on m.push_id = p.id
where p.type = 'CONSTANT'
and m.push_id = (
                  select max(push_id)
                  from multipliers
                  where push_id in (
                                      select push_id
                                      from pushes
                                      where type = 'CONSTANT'
                                   )
                );
```

or alternatively use a much simpler query derived from the initial one:

```
select *
from multipliers
where push_id = ( 
                  select max(push_id) 
                  from pushes 
                  where push_type = 'CONSTANT'
                )
```

Comment: great! and if I want to add a constraint on the pushes? such as a certain type of push only?

Comment: I added an alternative with the option to constraining by push_type.

Comment: I've found that `select m.*, p.type from multipliers m inner join pushes p on m.push_id = p.id where p.type= 'CONSTANT' order by p.id` returns all of the multiplier entries, but I'm still looking for an efficient way to get all rows with the max push_id from this result

Comment: Hi, this actually does not work between types. I've found that when inserting a push of a different type with multipliers, rerunning this query does not find the desired set of rows and instead returns nothing because the latest set of multiplier rows with push_id = max(push_id) has a push with a different type

Comment: That brings in new information that makes this simpler. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM 
multipliers INNER JOIN pushes 
ON multipliers.push_id = pushes.push_id 
ORDER BY multipliers.push_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

The `INNER JOIN` ensures that your are selecting the data from a `multiplier` which has a `push` record, with the dataset ordered by the largest `push_id`.

Following your comments, for additional criteria on the "push type", you could use:

```
SELECT * FROM 
multipliers INNER JOIN pushes 
ON multipliers.push_id = pushes.push_id 
WHERE pushes.type = 'X'
ORDER BY multipliers.push_id DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

---

#### EDIT:

Following the update to your question, you may need to do something like this:

```
select m.*, p.type 
from multipliers m inner join pushes p on m.push_id = p.id
where m.push_id = 
(
    select max(m2.push_id)
    from multipliers m2 inner join pushes p2 on m2.push_id = p2.id
    where p2.type = 'CONSTANT'
)
```

Comment: How can I add a constraint to a row for the pushes here? Such as only pulling multipliers from the latest push that is of type X.

Comment: @Riptyde4 I've revised my answer above ^^

Comment: This would not work because the relationship between multipliers and pushes is many to 1 as OP stated in his question and this would only return a single multiplier not many.

Comment: Yes, this returns only 1 multiplier.  I want the limit 1 on the amount of pushes to get the latest, not the multipliers.